# htaccess mod_rewrite url for subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently migrating a website between hosts, and I'm not getting the same behaviour from my htaccess file. The file code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

First rewrite is to https, and second rewrite is to php if html. As far as I can tell these both work fine.

The third rule is supposed to rewrite urls with no path type (html, php) to give them the php pathtype. This is where I'm having an issue.

This works fine for my main folder, e.g. staging.xyz.com/services returns staging.xyz.com/services in the address bar and the staging.xyz.com/services.php page.

When I have a subfolder called news, which has an index.php, it doesn't work on the new site.

On the old host entering staging.xyz.com/news would return staging.xyz.com/news/ in the address box and display the page at staging.xyz.com/news/index.php.

On the new host it still returns staging.xyz.co.nz/news/ in the address bar, but the rewrite returns staging.xyz.co.nz/news/.php, which errors out.

I wrote this a fair while ago for the old site, and htaccess this isn't my strong point, so I'm a little bit at a loss of why it worked on the old host but not the new one.

Is this an issue with the rewrite rule?

Comment: Try adding the following 2 conditions before your last rule :


`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Comment: Working perfectly with that, thanks starkeen. Now gonna go figure out what those conditions do.